# SDWebImage Issue while Archieve

Tags: iphone, sdwebimage

When i am trying to “Build Profile” everything is working fine. When i Archieve for submission, the SDWebImage is throwing error while importing UIImageView+WebCache.I m importing files as:
`#import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>`
I have been working on this since morning but couldn’t figure out why this is not working. Also, I have checked other SO questions in this regards but nothing helped. Also, In SDWebImage project, `libSDWebImage.a` is coming red. I am not able to reveal that in folder.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: have you done all what has been told in this link https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/ ?

Comment: Ya, Got the error, I was updating in USER HEADER SEARCHPATH instead of HEADER SEARCHPATH

Comment: but i did it before 15-16 days and it was ok ....

Answer (score 0):

I solved it very easily by adding (with quotes):

```
"$(SRCROOT)/SDWebImage"
```

to the various Header Search Paths under my project's Build Settings. Thanks to Lizard in [SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h file not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11033793/sdwebimage-uiimageviewwebcache-h-file-not-found) for his solution.